# How to show current cart product's details on checkout page

Tags: php, opencart

Hello guys,

Thanks in advance.
I am new to opencart and am currently developing a shopping cart in opencart and everything was going smoothly but I got stuck, help please

I want to access currently added cart items in checkout.tpl for generating an inquiry form, so I was editing controller/checkout.php and added these lines of code to access product details that are currently in the cart:

```
    //Product detail for Enquiry    
    $product_data = array();

    foreach ($this->cart->getProducts() as $product) {
        $option_data = array();

        foreach ($product['option'] as $option) {
            if ($option['type'] != 'file') {
                $value = $option['option_value'];   
            } else {
                $value = $this->encryption->decrypt($option['option_value']);
            }   

            $option_data[] = array(
                'product_option_id'       => $option['product_option_id'],
                'product_option_value_id' => $option['product_option_value_id'],
                'option_id'               => $option['option_id'],
                'option_value_id'         => $option['option_value_id'],                                   
                'name'                    => $option['name'],
                'value'                   => $value,
                'type'                    => $option['type']
            );                  
        }

        $product_data[] = array(
            'product_id' => $product['product_id'],
            'name'       => $product['name'],
            'model'      => $product['model'],
            'option'     => $option_data,
            'download'   => $product['download'],
            'quantity'   => $product['quantity'],
            'subtract'   => $product['subtract'],
            'price'      => $product['price'],
            'total'      => $product['total'],
            'tax'        => $this->tax->getTax($product['price'], $product['tax_class_id']),
            'reward'     => $product['reward']
        ); 
    }

    $data['products'] = $product_data;
```

and then added a line in checout/checkout.tpl :

```
    foreach ($products as $product)
    {
        echo 'yes am getting products details';
    }
```

**but still getting error: Undefined variable: products ?**

Am I doing it right? please correct me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have done is almost correct, however you've used

```
$data['products'] = $product_data;
```

where you should have put

```
$this->data['products'] = $product_data;
```